# Assign values to textview without final string

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, final

I got a problem in setting textview values.

```
String ID="";
......(code to assign ID values)

TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);

textViewToChange.setText(ID);
```

I got an error that let change ID to final.
but the ID is changeable, can't be final.
I tried EditText instead TextView, but got the same problem.

Is there any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Show the complete code. The code you've posted can't be causing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use your variable in some anonymous inner class so it has to be `final`. But it's changeable so it must not be `final`. This can be solved by using `final` *array* of size one.

```
final String[] ID= new String[1];
ID[0] = //assignment logic
...
textViewToChange.setText(ID[0]);
```

So your `ID` is `final` but you can change the values inside the array.